# I cannot get my program to import data from a txt into a Jtable

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist, jtable

My program is able to read my .txt file but for some reason, it is unable to put that data on my table. (if you need any other part of my code please tell me). I'm not sure exactly what the problem is but I have tried almost every way to input it into the table and nothing seems to work. I was able to manually input data into the table (with a create button) but for some reason, I cannot import data.

```
//initializing all of the buttons (and jtable, scroll pane)
this.jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
this.pokeTable = new JTable();
this.programTitle = new JLabel();
this.searchText = new JTextField();
this.searchButton = new JButton();
this.createButton = new JButton();
this.deleteButton = new JButton();
this.displayInstructionsButton = new JButton();
this.exportPokedex = new JButton();

//sets close operation
setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

//makes my Jtable
  this.pokeTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
  new Object[0][], 
  new String[] {"Name", "Region", "PokeNumber", "Type", "Habitat" }) //creating column headings
  {
    boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[5];

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) //makes all of the cells editable
    {
      return this.canEdit[columnIndex]; 
    }
  });


  IO.openInputFile("data/pokemon.txt");
  int j =0;
  while(IO.readLine()!=null){   
    j++;
  }
  IO.closeInputFile();

  IO.openInputFile("data/pokemon.txt");

  String[] pokemon2 = new String[5];

  for(int i = j; i!=0; i--)
  {

    String s = IO.readLine();
    pokemon2 = s.split(",");


    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)this.pokeTable.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[] { pokemon2[0], pokemon2[1], Integer.valueOf(pokemon2[2]), pokemon2[3], pokemon2[4] });
     new Pokemon (pokemon2[0], pokemon2[1], Integer.valueOf(pokemon2[2]), pokemon2[3], pokemon2[4]);
    for(int f = 0; f < pokemon2.length; f++){
        System.out.println(pokemon2[f]);
        System.out.println("");
    }
  }

  IO.closeInputFile();  

this.jScrollPane1.setViewportView(this.pokeTable); //makes table able to scroll
this.jScrollPane1.getViewport().setBackground(new Color (233, 116, 81)); //sets background of table (not cell colour)
//end of intializing JTable

//sets title of the program
this.programTitle.setText("Pokedex");
```

Comment: Using SO as a debugger is a terrible idea. What have you tried as far as debugging small programs? Have you attempted to debug or print values to test your assertions?

Answer (score 0):

My advice for you would be to split up the different variables, you are trying to do too much in one step, instead of

```
this.pokeTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
new Object[0][],new String[] {"Name", "Region", "PokeNumber", "Type", "Habitat" })
```

Create separate variables

```
String[] headers = {"Name", "Region", "PokeNumber", "Type", "Habitat" };
Object[][] arr = new Object[fileLength][headers.length];
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(arr, headers);
this.pokeTable.setModel(model);
```

Generally, this can weed out many little errors, and then keep writing check statements to narrow down exactly where about's the problem occurs; when it is working you can narrow it into one line, but breaking it down can often be enough to find and fix bugs. Maybe try populating the array first before you try and create the table. Some code I have that achieves this result but with a database is:

```
Object[][] data;

//Get data from table and convert to 2D array
data = new Object[len][columnNames.length];
String sql = "SELECT * FROM SHM";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
int x = 0;
while (rs.next()){
    for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
       data[x][i] = new Double(rs.getDouble(columnNames[i]));
    }                
    x++;
}
rs.close();
//Output data
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table");
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Try implementing it in this sort of format, splitting it up to ensure that yours works, create the 2Darray from the file before putting it into the table, instead of creating a table and trying to add new rows to it that way; if you later want to add a new row, have it re-draw the table out again. If this still does not work, I am not sure sorry.